# Import Custom DAO Jar Class File Not Found Exception

Tags: dao, classnotfoundexception, jdbctemplate

I developed a DAO war project using Spring JDBC template which has applicationContext.xml in it and export as jar. Then, I had created another jar project which import the DAO jar but it throw below stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.breeze.bis.dao.service.jdbcTemplate] for bean with name 'genericDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breeze.bis.dao.service.jdbcTemplate
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1263)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:898)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:588)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.breeze.dao.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breeze.bis.dao.service.jdbcTemplate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1255)
    ... 9 more
```

The DAO jar is import as library, required project in build path and order and export tab in eclipse but how come URLClassLoader not able to load the class since the jar consists of the mention class.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread closed because of wrong class name in applicationContext.xml